# State in componentDidMount always null, there should be data from the task variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, native-base

I have a problem, every i call state "modalData" in componentDidMount, state always null, there should be data from the task variable.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.tasksRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/'+ this.props.card_id);
    this.state = {
        modalData : null,
    }
}

componentDidMount(tasksRef){
    var task = [];
    tasksRef.on('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
        task.push({
            about : dataSnapshot.val().about, 
            card : dataSnapshot.val().card,
            company : dataSnapshot.val().company,
            first_name : dataSnapshot.val().first_name,
            job_title : dataSnapshot.val().job_title,
            last_name : dataSnapshot.val().last_name,
            photo : dataSnapshot.val().photo,
            role : dataSnapshot.val().role,
            thumbnail : dataSnapshot.val().thumbnail,
            title : dataSnapshot.val().title,
            website : dataSnapshot.val().website,
            _key : dataSnapshot.key
        });
        console.log('dataSnapshot.val().first_name : ' + dataSnapshot.val().first_name);
    });
    console.log(task); //there is data
    this.setState({
        modalData : task,
    });
    console.log(this.state.modalData); //there is no data
}
```

Comment: componentDidMount method does not take argument https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: ^ this and use `this.taskRef` instead.

Comment: Move `this.setState` inside of `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 3):

setState is asynchronous, so you'll need to add a callback to display the console.log i.e.,:

```
this.setState({ modalData: task }, () => console.log(this.state));
```

[setState Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: If like that, how can i call state in component ?  ex : <Text>{this.state.modalData.first_name}</Text>

Comment: getting the state is synchronous, setting it is not.

Answer (score -1):

Logging it after setting won't work. You can use

```
 this.state.modalData = task
```

, then logging it . That would work. for your logging.

Comment: You shouldn't directly modify the state, that's incorrect.